# How to check if a server has a fixed IP address using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, script, ip, windows-server-2016, powershell-ise

for me to check if the server has a fixed IP address at the moment I go through a long process, as described on the pictures below, in order, and that is for `windows server 2016`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

my question is:

is there a way to get access to quick info like
`does this server has a fixed ip address?` and
`what is the ip address of this server?`

using powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

The following code will help you get on the way, but there's a catch. A server can have multiple network adapters, such as Ethernet, Wifi and VPN, and each can have its own settings. You can get the list of all but your script won't be able to figure out which one is the main one.

The code is as follows:

```
$IpConfig = Get-NetIPConfiguration

$IpConfig

Get-NetIPInterface -ifindex $IpConfig.InterfaceIndex | select ifIndex,ifAlias,Dhcp, AddressFamily
```